# How to get part of input value with php?

Tags: php

i have form with post method...

Input values is only links, like -`http://site/see?v=ID`
How to get only `ID` and add it to `$var-id="";`?

Comment: If the form values are appearing in the URL then you're using GET, not POST...

Comment: `http://site/see?v=ID` its sample of input value @animuson

Answer (score 1):

**HTML:**

```
<input type="hidden" name="link" value="http://site/see?v=12345" />
```

**PHP:**

```
$link = explode('=',$_POST['link']);
$link = $link[1]; // 12345
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use php functions strpos & substr

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on how much your data varies, but here's a technique that will work with more complex urls:

```
// assuming $url = 'http://site/see?something=blah&v=ID&foo=bar'
$qs = parse_str(substr($url, strpos($url, '?')+1));
$varId = $qs['v'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$html = 'http://site/see?v=ID';
$var-id = explode('=',$html);
$var-id = $var-id[1];
?>
```

Comment: You should really look at the existing answers before posting one that was already provided ;)

Comment: lol.  I sometimes have my window open too long (multitasking).  Don't want to steal your thunder. +1 to you.  I always prefer exploding to using regex.